# How to create a slider bar with 2 mutually influencing thumbs in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Sorry, when I wanted to do this feature, it was the first time I learned jQuery. I have inquired a lot of web pages and questions, but I haven't been able to implement it in the past few days. Really hope someone can help me!

My idea is to create a slider with two thumbs like the video below. When one of the thumbs is moved, the other will also change (if one is **x** and the other is **y**, the value entered by the user is **a**. Then the relationship between the two may be **y = 2a-x**)

I used the following .css and jQuery to create a slider (with a lot of useless code removed):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
    $( function() {
      $( "#myRange" ).slider({
        range: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        values: [80, 120],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
          var x = ui.values[0];
          var y = ui.values[1];
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

and

```
<input type="number"/>
<div id="myRange"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myRange").slider({
    range: false,
    min: -200,
    max: 200,
    values: [80, -80],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var x, y, a = parseInt($("#a").val());
      if ($(".ui-slider-handle.ui-state-focus").index() == 0) {
        x = ui.values[0];
        y = (2 * a) - x;
        $(this).slider("values", 1, y);
      } else {
        y = ui.values[1];
        x = (2 * a) - y;
        $(this).slider("values", 0, x);
      }
      $("#x-val").html(x);
      $("#a-val").html(a);
      $("#y-val").html(y);

    }
  });
});
```

```css
input[type='number'] {
  width: 3em;
}

#myRange {
  margin: 10px;
}

#myRange .ui-slider-handle:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

#myRange .ui-slider-handle:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.log span {
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <div class="ui-widget-content" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <label for="a">Enter Number</label>
    <input type="number" id="a" value="0" />
  </div>
  <div id="myRange"></div>
</div>
<div class="log">
  <label>X:</label><span id="x-val">80</span><label>A:</label><span id="a-val">0</span><label>Y:</label><span id="y-val">120</span>
</div>
```

The tricky part in this is that the user can grab either Handle. Knowing which handle has the Focus allows us to assign the proper value.

**Update**

You can tighten it up a bit too:

```
$(function() {
  $("#myRange").slider({
    range: false,
    min: -200,
    max: 200,
    values: [80, -80],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var a = parseInt($("#a").val());
      if ($(".ui-slider-handle.ui-state-focus").index() == 0) {
        $(this).slider("values", 1, (2 * a) - ui.values[0]);
      } else {
        $(this).slider("values", 0, (2 * a) - ui.values[1]);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: My god, that’s awesome. It is almost perfect, thank you very much for your help!